# cannot find the system.web.UI namespace in a project reference in visual studio 2010 for the target framework ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

while I got error "using System.Web.UI" as namespace not found. I tried to figure it out by adding the reference. But unfortunately in the .NET tab I couldn't find System.Web.UI component while other components were there. How to solve the issue ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, my original answer was based on the original version of the question...

Next up: do you have a reference to `System.Web.dll` which is the assembly which includes at least many of the classes in `System.Web.UI`?

Comment: yap that was a typo in my question. Now edited. And yes I want the namespace using System.Web.UI

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud: Well that's wasted my time for no reason... *please* be more careful in future. Do you have a reference to the System.Web.dll assembly?

Comment: I have attached the screenshot what I found on my question.

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud: That looks like it's a display oddity... what exact project type do you have?

Comment: I have found the assembly in C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0   and my project type is ASP.NET web application

Comment: @Md.ArafatAlMahmud: You shouldn't do that - you should just add a reference within the normal .NET tab. You shouldn't need to browse to a particular file. Frankly I'd expect System.Web.dll to be a reference by default though...